# node js : mysql Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: php, mysql, linux, node.js, ubuntu-14.04

First, here is my code.
    var mysql = require('mysql');

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host    :'192.168.0.106', //or 'localhost'
    port: 3306, //this is my default port
    user : 'root',
    password : 'asdqwe1234',
    database:'db_test'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('mysql connection error');
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
});
```

but result is this.

```
mysql connection error
{ [Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.] fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
E:\htdocs\testserver.js:15
        throw err;
              ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (E:\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:103:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (E:\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:48)
at Protocol.handshake (E:\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (E:\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\htdocs\testserver.js:11:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

My server info is 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64).
And my server has apache 2.4, php 5.5.9, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3.

I checked mysql port, but is fine.
There's no problem and db access in php is working fine too.
I disabled ubuntu firewall and I checked so many things but it always same error. I even connect mysql through node.js!

..I tried so many times but I couldn't handle this problem so I need some help.
Please help me what is the problem and what makes work properly. thank you.

Comment: works for me. But how are you working on an ubuntu server with a driver letter? `E:\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:103`. Drop your windows machine and use `localhost` on the unix box first to test. Also note that localhost authentication differs from any User@% authentication in a mysql server.

Comment: mysql connection error
{ [Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.] fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }

/home/redsoap/node-v0.10.33/testserver.js:15
        throw err;
              ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/redsoap/node-v0.10.33/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:103:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/redsoap/node-v0.10.33/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
..

Comment: I tested two operation system(win, linux ubuntu) but it always took up same error in same code(part).

Comment: how did you installed the npm mysql module? Try to install a local one.

Comment: npm install mysql
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 http is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No README data
mysql@2.7.0 node_modules/mysql
├── require-all@1.0.0
├── bignumber.js@2.0.7
└── readable-stream@1.1.13 (inherits@2.0.1, isarray@0.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.31, core-util-is@1.0.1)

Comment: I reinstalled mysql module but not solved yet. Is this problem with my computer? Sometimes it tooks error message...